# applicationtimeout - ColdFusion 8

Tags: coldfusion

I inherited a coldfusion website that is written in ColdFusion 8 and it was written VERY poorly.

- First: the Application.cfm is encrypted
- Second: no one know how to decrypt the Application.cfm so I have no idea what are listed in this Application.cfm

Is there a way to get and display the applicationtimeout set in cfapplication?

I'm able to cfdump the "#Application.applicationName#" but not sure how to cfdump the applicationtimeout, sessiontimeout attributes from the cfapplication

Can anyone help?

Comment: How do you know it's poorly written when you can't read it?

Answer (score 2):

It's easy enough to decrypt the files. Just google "[coldfusion cfdecrypt.exe](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=coldfusion%20cfdecrypt.exe)" and track one down. Examples:

- [cfdecrypt.exe](https://github.com/disccomp/cfdecrypt/tree/master/Windows)
- [AdeptCFDecrypt](http://www.adeptdeveloper.com/software/adeptcfdecrypt/dispOverview.cfm)

Note that the encryption scheme used *changed* for - I think -  CF10, so these solutions won't work on that or later versions of CF. However it should be fine for your purposes.